# What is Assistant file in OpenAI Assistant API?

Tags: openai-api

I am working with OpenAI Assistants and want to understand if I create a assistant file then does that mean I don't have to provide file ids while creating the threads?

We can provide file ids while creating an Assistant [link](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/assistants/modifyAssistant)

```
assistant = client.beta.assistants.create(
  name="Data visualizer",
  description="You are great at creating beautiful data visualizations. You analyze data present in .csv files, understand trends, and come up with data visualizations relevant to those trends. You also share a brief text summary of the trends observed.",
  model="gpt-4-1106-preview",
  tools=[{"type": "code_interpreter"}],
  file_ids=[file.id]
)
```

We can create assistant file [link](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/assistants/createAssistantFile)

```
assistant_file = client.beta.assistants.files.create(
  assistant_id="asst_abc123", 
  file_id="file-abc123"
)
```

We can provide file ids while creating threads as well [link](https://platform.openai.com/docs/assistants/how-it-works/managing-threads-and-messages)

```
thread = client.beta.threads.create(

  messages=[
    {
      "role": "user",
      "content": "Create 3 data visualizations based on the trends in this file.",
      "file_ids": [file.id]
    }
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer to my question.

Basically we can attach files with the assistant at the time of creation of assistant and another way to attach file to assistant is to create assistant file [link](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/assistants/createAssistantFile)
and the third option that I have provided above *file ids while creating threads* is to inject files in the ongoing conversation which is a thread.

I got to understand this while playing around on Openai's playground also a reddit user answered me on reddit here's the link to it [reddit post link](https://www.reddit.com/r/OpenAI/comments/1864fsi/comment/kb5ybsa/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)